# phpmyadmin - ubuntu11.10 version - No privilage to create new database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm using ubuntu 11.10, apache2,When i open PHPMyadmin, i'm not able to create new database it is showing "No Privilege". But When i Create through command line(terminal) i can create in mysql.., Why this error is coming, can any one help me out.

Answer (score 2):

When you install phpmyadmin on ubuntu, you create an user with usage privileges only.

To create database in phpmyadmin, you have to log as **root** with the **mysql password**.